# How to continue numbering within the Appendix equation?

Tags: numbering, appendix

I would like to continue the numbering of equations that I have in my paper in the Appendix section. Right now, the equations are numbered (A.1), (A.2), .... I would like them to appear as a continuation of the equation numbered in my previous sections in the paper.

```
\appendix\newpage\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\section{Appendix}
\label{Appendix}

    \subsection{Proofs}
    \label{proofs}
    \noindent {\it Proof of Lemma 1}. Consider Case 1 
    \begin{align}
        x = 1 + y,\label{eqn:40}
    \end{align}\\
    and 
    \begin{align}
        m = bx -c.\label{eqn:41}
    \end{align}\\ $\blacksquare$\\
```

Instead of being labeled (40) and (41) the equations appear as (A.1) and (A.2) How do I change that?

Comment: Remove `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` as you don't want `equation`s to be "numbered within" `section`s.

Comment: You should also replace `{\it Proof of Lemma 1}` with `\textit{Proof of Lemma 1}`.

Comment: Thanks to all the above comments and suggestions. They have helped a lot!